# Are there any side missions you cannot complete later in the game?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'd like to play through the entire game once just completing the core missions, then on my second or third playthrough, really explore the side missions. Are there any side missions that "go away" and cannot be done once progress has been made on the main mission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Blocked mission?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85503/what-is-a-blocked-mission)

Comment: @BenBrocka not sure if this is a dupe, he's asking if missions will disappear if he waits on them, not if missions become unblocked later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all the side quests can be completed after you beat the main mission.  In fact, skipping side quests is a good strategy on playthrough 2 as the quest rewards in playthrough 2.5 will be boosted to the max level of 50, so you can get good rewards such as a level 50 [teapot](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Teapot).

You just have to make sure you do not accept the quest until you reach playthrough 2.5.

Comment: Skipped side missions in playthrough 1 are only good for working towards challenges. When I go back like this, I'm always in a nova shield, crouched with a bladed assault rifle :)

Comment: Is that the same kind of teapot that is in orbit around the sun somewhere between Earth and Mars?

Comment: @Alex its more AWESOME since it face melts groups of enemies at the same time

Comment: You can't prove the teapot I'm referring to doesn't do that too! </ burden of proof>