# Will I lose my shot at the Law pistol if i complete Playthrough 1?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have krieg up to lv 30 and am just finishing up a few things before I kill the warrior. One thing I have put off is getting the Law pistol and Order shield. I want them to be as high level as possible for playthrough 2. I am aware that the only real use i will be getting out of the law is in the form of its +100% melee damage, so it's level is less important. Nevertheless, I want it to be lv 30 or close to it for Playthrough 2. At the moment the mission is recommended lv 16, so I expect the gun will be simmilar (lv 16 or 17).

I noticed that several missions get locked out when I turn in the mission Data Mining; so my 2-part question is this:

(1) If I proceed with the main storyline, turn in Data Mining, kill the warrior, and complete Playthrough 1; will I still be able to accept and complete the mission "Won't Get Fooled Again" from Marshall Friedman and get the law? 
(2) If so, will that scale the law up to lv 31 to match my level and completion of playthrough 1; or will the Law pistol still be lv 16?

Comment: see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work?rq=1) and [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97982/are-there-any-side-missions-you-cannot-complete-later-in-the-game). They answer part of your question. Also, it's known that once you "accept" a quest, the quest level and it's rewards are "locked-in" at that level which you accepted it at.

Comment: In playthrough 2 that is true, but appearently in playthrough 1 it is not the case. In playthrough 1 all quest rewards are set to the level they become available, so I CAN wait to complete the mission, but the reward will still only be lv 16. Pity, I really hoped to have a better Law for playthrough 2, and with that being impossible it certainly would have been helpful to have done it asap and had it for the last 14 levels...

Answer (score 0):

It will be level 16. I would advise going in to Ult Vault Hunter (or true), and getting it then. Because on ult it will be on level.

Answer (score 0):

this question basically answers mine.

[Which is better: side quests after killing the warrior or Playthrough 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/which-is-better-side-quests-after-killing-the-warrior-or-playthrough-2?rq=1)

Though it was phrased differently, and seems to be more related to leveling up a character, it was later answered with "quest rewards from side missions **outside** of DLC's but **inside** of playthrough 1 **do not** scale after beating the warrior, but missions in DLC's do".

Comment: If anyone with the power to close this question feels like doing so I would not blame you.